# nginx node.js & socket.io 504 timeout

Tags: nginx, node.js, socket

Nginx config

```
server {
    listen        *:80;
    server_name   live.domain.com;

    server_tokens off;
    charset utf-8;

        error_log       /var/log/nginx/live-error.log info;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/live-access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

When node.js is working everything is okay, but if node.js not started and I try to load page http://live.domain.com/socket.io/socket.io.js it makes me wait 30 seconds (read_timeout).

I want make it so, that if node.js **not running** I'm getting 404 or 502 error right away without 30 seconds waiting for timeout.

In other words: I need to check node.js on client side right away.

Answer (score 1):

A flexible solution would be to use [`upstream`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html):

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:1337    max_fails=1 fail_timeout=5s;
}

server {
    listen        *:80;
    server_name   live.domain.com;

    server_tokens off;
    charset utf-8;

        error_log       /var/log/nginx/live-error.log info;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/live-access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

This way you can additionally control how many failures are tolerated and you can have multiple servers in one upstream.

Answer (score 0):

Set proxy_connect_timeout to lower value:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 2s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer here, there could also be a problem with csf if you're on Linux:

https://serverfault.com/a/713874/150138